# crm 2011 (on prem) - roaming addin?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have CRM 2011 on prem (soon to be upgraded to 2015 on prem). We use an integrated security setup i.e. once logged into machine no further login to crm required. We have users who move around and use different machines. Is it possible to configure the crm addin for outlook such that it too follows the roaming users around? I don't fully understand the outlook setup but I assume it uses roaming profiles as for the roaming users, the outlook looks the same no matter what machine they log onto. My question is if it is possible to setup the crm for outlook addin such that it too shows up in outlook no matter what machine they are on?

Comment: You have to install it everywhere, then it will work as you want.

Comment: @Alex thanks. Am I right in thinking that we also have to configure every user on any machine they want the addin on? If a user is configured on multiple addins, only 1 of them can be the "synchonizing" client. So how is that supposed to work I wonder? Why can't an addin just go with a roaming outlook?

Comment: Took the comment and made it a proper answer, tl,dr: install it everywhere, then it (almost) "just works"

Comment: @Alex thanks. Checkmarked your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to setup the Outlook client on all involved machines. People would then be able to use it everywhere, the only caveat would be the "primary" vs "secondary" clients distinction:

If a user is setup on more than one Outlook client, you'll see a message about "choosing the synchronization client". What that means is, only one client can be the "primary" client, the others will be "secondary".

Being the primary synchronization client only affects Outlook data. All CRM data is synced the same way no matter if the client is the primary or a secondary.

Contacts, Tasks, and Appointments sync slightly differently between primary and secondary clients. When the primary client tracks, updates, or deletes one of these Outlook objects, they will immediately be synced back to CRM. When a secondary client does, the changes will not be synced back to CRM until the primary client performs its next sync.

Emails and the tracking of emails are handled the same for both primary and secondary client.